# Magento 2 - Location path of the SQL query file which inserts orders in to database

Tags: magento2, database, file, locations

I want to **modify** the values of the product items will be inserted to table 'sales_order_item'  right before the order is placed.

So im trying to locate where the exact query is.

Also the order confirmation mail should sent the **modified** item values not the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i basically solved this by adding my code to `public_html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/success.phtml`

So it gets updated only once and not everytime when the order is saved in the backend.
If you want to see what code i have put there, then here you go

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();

$sqlx = "SELECT * FROM sales_order ORDER BY entity_id DESC LIMIT 1";
$connection->query($sqlx);
$resultx = $connection->fetchAll($sqlx);
foreach($resultx as $resulx)
{
    $entityid  = $resulx['entity_id']; 
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM sales_order_item WHERE order_id='$entityid'";
$connection->query($sql);
$results = $connection->fetchAll($sql);

foreach($results as $result)
{
    $item_id = $result['item_id'];

    /* DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE */     

    $upsql = "UPDATE sales_order_item SET product_options='$finalque' WHERE item_id='$item_id'";
    $connection->query($upsql);
    }
}
```